# xcopy /s /y "$(SolutionDir)packages\Apache.Ignite.1.6.0\Libs\*.*" "$(TargetDir)Libs" error while building in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, post-build-event

Hello All,
               while building Visual project project from jenkins  am getting below error i have set msbuild plugin and set path in jenkins.

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: The command " [C:\Users\Administrator.jenkins\workspace\DrawingsFabric\DrawingsFabricApi\DrawingsFabricApi.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: if not exist "C:\Users\Administrator.jenkins\workspace\DrawingsFabric\DrawingsFabricApi\bin\x64\Debug\Libs" md "C:\Users\Administrator.jenkins\workspace\DrawingsFabric\DrawingsFabricApi\bin\x64\Debug\Libs" [C:\Users\Administrator.jenkins\workspace\DrawingsFabric\DrawingsFabricApi\DrawingsFabricApi.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: xcopy /s /y "*Undefined*packages\Apache.Ignite.2.2.0\Libs*.*" "C:\Users\Administrator.jenkins\workspace\DrawingsFabric\DrawingsFabricApi\bin\x64\Debug\Libs"" exited with code 4. [C:\Users\Administrator.jenkins\workspace\DrawingsFabric\DrawingsFabricApi\DrawingsFabricApi.csproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Administrator.jenkins\workspace\DrawingsFabric\DrawingsFabricApi\DrawingsFabricApi.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\Administrator.jenkins\workspace\DrawingsFabric\DrawingsFabricApi\DrawingsFabricApi.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(ResolveAssemblyReferences target) ->

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved your issue? If not, Please let me know the latest information about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to the error log:

> error MSB3073: xcopy /s /y "**Undefined**packages\Apache.Ignite.**2.2.0**\Libs*.*"

You can find `$(SolutionDir)` is **Undefined**.

That because you may build the a single project (NOT Solution) in jenkins. In this case, MSBuild running each project independently not the Solution, so MSBuild could not find the define for `$(SolutionDir)`. It worked fine in Visual Studio, but not on the build server.

**To resolve this issue**, you can use **`$(ProjectDir)..\`** instead of **`$(SolutionDir)`**

So the command line should be:

```
if not exist "$(TargetDir)Libs" md "$(TargetDir)Libs" 
xcopy /s /y "$(ProjectDir)..\packages\Apache.Ignite.2.2.0\Libs\*.*" "$(TargetDir)Libs"
```

But, I found the command line in the error log is not same as in the title, so you may need to double check the command line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you i solved the issues by giveing $solutionDIR Path in jenkins :).