# Unable to get correct MSBuildCommunityTasksPath when using MSBUILDTASKS from NuGet in a before.Solution.sln.targets script run on TFS build server

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

I have been using MSBUILDTASKS (installed from NuGet) successfully in project-level targets files, run on TFS build server, for a long time. Now I am trying to use it in solution-level Before and After targets file ([see here](http://sedodream.com/2010/10/22/MSBuildExtendingTheSolutionBuild.aspx)).

However, used this way, it seems unable to form the correct path to the MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll as specified in the MSBuildCommunityTasksPath property in my targets file.

If I set it like this:

```
<MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(SolutionDir)\.build</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
```

then I get this error:

*D:\Builds\Agents\17\DevelopmentSTP1\My.Product\src\before.My.Product.sln.targets (9): The imported project "D:\.build\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.*

The actual path on the build server to the DLL is: D:\Builds\Agents\17\DevelopmentSTP1\My.Product\src\.build , so it looked like $(SolutionDir) was returning a blank, however that made no sense as $(SolutionDir) is used elsewhere in the script successfully.

If I set it like this:

`<MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(SolutionDir).build</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>`  (i.e. without the backslash)

then I get this error:

*D:\Builds\Agents\17\DevelopmentSTP1\My.Product\src\before.My.Product.sln.targets (18): The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Attrib" task could not be loaded from the assembly D:\Builds\Agents\17\DevelopmentSTP1\My.Product\src\.build\.build\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Builds\Agents\17\DevelopmentSTP1\My.Product\src\.build\.build\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.*

The path is almost right now, but note the doubling of the folder name: \.build\.build

I have tried a lot of tricks to try to get it to work, like adding ..\ to try to get it to step back a folder level, but nothing works so long as I retain the $(SolutionDir) variable. The only thing that works is to hard code the physical path in, i.e.

```
<MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>D:\Builds\Agents\17\DevelopmentSTP1\My.Product\src\.build</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
```

Any ideas how I can make it work without hard-coding a path?

Thanks

Comment: I have posted this as an issue in the GitHub project (https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/issues/268).

Comment: According to your description, this issue seems not related to tfsbuild, more related to msbuild side. Please take a look at  this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722779/xcopy-s-y-solutiondirpackages-apache-ignite-1-6-0-libs-targetdirl/46727448#46727448  MSBuild running each project independently not the Solution, so MSBuild could not find the define for $(SolutionDir). It worked fine in Visual Studio, but not on the build server. See if it helps you.

Comment: No, that is not the problem. By definition the solution-level Before and After targets file are triggered by building the solution. You can see that $(SolutionDir) is defined because in my 2nd example, the path does include the solution directory, it just has this strange doubling of the folder name: \.build\.build

Comment: Hi Laurence, if so, have you tried remove .build of &(SolutionDiR) such as  `<MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(SolutionDir)`</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>` There should without  the backslash , cause `&(SolutionDiR)`  will contain `\` in the last character, you could double confirm this in VS project property.

Comment: Hi Patrick. I didn't understand your comment very well ... if you meant me to try using <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(SolutionDir)</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath> then this is the result: D:\Builds\Agents\17\DevelopmentSTP1\My.Product\src\before.My.Product.sln.targets (9): The imported project "D:\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" was not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer thanks to user VonOgre on Github. He said:

... the metaproj emitted by msbuild for a solution imports the before.*.sln.targets prior to defining the $(SolutionDir) property ... The before-solution targets will not yet have $(SolutionDir) available when doing their own imports, resulting in blanks but the after-solution targets would .... You might consider utilizing $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory) or $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) instead of $(SolutionDir), since those are low-level MSBuild properties. Either one would work in this case since before/after.*.sln.targets files need to be siblings to the solution file.

So the short answer is: don't use $(SolutionDir) in a before-solution targets file - use  $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory) instead.

See https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/issues/268